# Calling CodeIgniter controller method returns 404

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404

First attempt with CI, and get a "page not found" error when use Ajax to call method.  Have double-checked the names, and just lost at sea now.

```
[page_a.php]
<script>
  function f1() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?= site_url("controller_a/method_a") ?>',
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    var msg = '';
         if (jqXHR.status == 0            ) msg = 'Not connected, verify network [000]';
    else if (jqXHR.status == 404          ) msg = 'Requested page not found [404]';
    else if (jqXHR.status == 500          ) msg = 'Internal server error [500]';
    else if (exception    == 'parsererror') msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed';
    else if (exception    == 'timeout'    ) msg = 'Time out error';
    else if (exception    == 'abort'      ) msg = 'Ajax request aborted';
    else                                    msg = jqXHR.responseText;
    alert(msg);
}});}
</script>

[controller_a.php]
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class controller_a extends MY_Controller {
public function method_a() {
    echo '<script>alert(":-)");</script>';
}}
```

Comment: Many possibilities.. is your controller really extending a custom base controller? if not, you should extend CI_Controller instead.
Also, remember both the file name and the class name of a controller must start with an uppercase letter (so `class Controller_a extends MY_Controller` and Controller_a.php would be the appropriate names)

Comment: Thanks, have changed it to extend CI_Controller, and use uppercase, but still the same error.

Comment: include index.php in your url incase if you have not configured index.php, open google chrome console and show where the request is going, show the entire url, visit the url and check what's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('Controller/method')?>",
```

Try this keep the Controller's first letter capital and echo the site url.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **routes.php** file. probably there is another redirect in this file.
and

Answer (score 0):

```
[page_a.php]
<script>
  function f1() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?= site_url("index.php/Controller_a/Method_a") ?>'
});}
</script>

[Controller_a.php]
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller_a extends CI_Controller {
public function Method_a() {
    echo '<script>alert(":-)");</script>';
}}
```

Tried the uppercase, extend CI_Controller, and index.php, but no luck yet.

I noticed that if I use

```
<?= site_url("Controller_a/Method_a") ?>
```

in the html, so that it's called when the page loaded/rendered, then the method is found and called, but just not found when dynamically called with Ajax/JS after the page is loaded.

In the console the address is

```
www.example.com/Controller_a/Method_a
```

The actual address is

```
www.example.com/web/content/application/controllers/Controller_a.php
```